# Variable replacement with ${string//variable1/variable2} issue in unix

Tags: string, shell, unix, ksh

Hello I am trying to replace a string with another string.

This is my sample

$SITE has been already declared

```
PARAM="$SITE,90,1000"
PARAM=${PARAM//'$SITE'/$SITE}
```

but I am getting this error

```
PARAMS="${PARAMS//"\$SITE"/$SITE}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
```

What is causing this "\ to show up in unix execution?

It works when I do it straight from Shell script.

But these parameters are taken from a text file where I build the PARAM variables.
In the end i do an sqlplus statment where i exec procedure(parameters,...);

what is the issue in this scenario?

Comment: What is value of `$SITE`?

Comment: `set -vx` to see how the shell is executing each line. The `'$SITE'` that you use in PARAM=... is the equivalent of `"\$SITE"` displayed in the error msg. As SITE is already declared, try `PARAM=${PARAM//"$SITE"/$SITE}`. Good luck.

Comment: ok ad what is your expected output for `PARAM`?

Comment: PARAMS is `$SITE,90,1000`  but since sqlplus is reading it as $SITE, i want to use the replace method to replace the literal site with the value $SITE has been passed.

So i want params to end up like `12,90,1000`

Answer (score 1):

What version of ksh do you have?

```
$ SITE=42
$ PARAM='$SITE,90,1000'
$ echo ${PARAM//\$SITE/$SITE}
42,90,1000
$ echo ${PARAM//'$SITE'/$SITE}
42,90,1000
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead?

```
PARAM=$SITE${PARAM#\$SITE}
```

Removes the literal string $SITE from the beginning of `$PARAM`, then prepends the actual value of `$SITE`.

```
> SITE=12
> PARAM='$SITE,90,1000'
> echo $PARAM 
$SITE,90,1000
> echo "$SITE${PARAM#\$SITE}"
12,90,1000
```